# How To Sum A Varchar Data Type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008 I have a table with similar structure.  Unfortunately changing the data structure is not an option, so I am stuck with attempting to come up with an alternative.  I have tried to run this query, but I get an error of:

> (5 row(s) affected)
>   Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 9
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Here is DDL - what syntax should be changed in the query in order for me to receive valid output and not an error message?

```
Declare @GreenHouse Table
(nomen varchar(100), vtc varchar(100), d1 date)

Insert Into @GreenHouse (nomen, vtc, d1) VALUES
('Green', '507.02', '2016-01-14'), ('Green', '4.44089e-015', '2016-01-03')
,('Green', '200.57', '2016-01-18'), ('Green', '649.01', '2016-01-19'),
('Green', '1849.85', '2016-04-30')

Select nomen, Round(Sum(Cast(vtc As Decimal(10,2))),0.00) As FormatedInfo, d1
FROM @GreenHouse Group By nomen, d1 Order By d1 DESC
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `4.44089e-015` is most likely giving you the error by trying to convert it to a `decimal`. Try using `float` instead:

```
SELECT  nomen, 
        ROUND(SUM(CAST(vtc AS float)),0.00) FormatedInfo, 
        d1
FROM @GreenHouse 
GROUP BY nomen, d1 
ORDER BY d1 DESC;
```

The results with your sample data are:

```
╔═══════╦══════════════╦════════════╗
║ nomen ║ FormatedInfo ║     d1     ║
╠═══════╬══════════════╬════════════╣
║ Green ║         1850 ║ 2016-04-30 ║
║ Green ║          649 ║ 2016-01-19 ║
║ Green ║          201 ║ 2016-01-18 ║
║ Green ║          507 ║ 2016-01-14 ║
║ Green ║            0 ║ 2016-01-03 ║
╚═══════╩══════════════╩════════════╝
```

(yeah, I know that it converts the `4.44089e-015` value to `0`, but it is expected for a float)

Comment: very nice, I always thought decimal was the way to go, but here float is.  Thank yoU!